# Why is name Node not defined?

Tags: python

I am new to Python and i am getting this error, but am unsure why:

`NameError: name 'Node' is not defined`

```
class Node:
# initialisation/constructor
    def __init__(self):
        self.parents = []
        self.children = []
        self.parentWeights = []
        self.nodeWeight = 0.0

    # add child to node
    def addChild(self, child, weight):
        self.children.append(child)

    # add parent with weight to node
    def addParent(self, parent, weight):
        self.parents.append(parent)
        self.parentWeights.append(weight)

        if not self in parent.children:
            parent.addChild(self, weight)

    def calculateWeight(self):
        weightSum = sum(self.parentWeights)*self.nodeWeight
        self.nodeWeight = weightSum

    # run main function if not a library

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        i1 = Node()
        i2 = Node()
        h1 = Node()
        h2 = Node()
        o1 = Node()

        h1.addParent(i1, 1)
        h1.addParent(i2, 1)
        h2.addParent(i2, 1)
        h2.addParent(i2, 1)
        o1.addParent(h1, -1)
        o1.addParent(h2, 1)

        i1.nodeWeight = 3
        i2.nodeWeight = 5
        calculateWeight(h1)
        calculateWeight(h2)
        calculateWeight(o1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call `Node` within the definition of `Node`. You have to do it outside. Fixing your indentation in the end of the code should do.

By fixing the indentation I mean that: take everything from `if __name__ == "__main__":` until the end, and dedent it 4 spaces.

Comment: You can call `Node` within its own class definition. The only problem is the indentation.

Comment: Try this: `class C: C()` (with a newline after the `:`). You will get `NameError: name 'C' is not defined`.

Answer (score 2):

Your indentation is wrong. Your part `if __name__ == '__main__'` is part of your definition of `class Node`.

It should look like:

```
class Node:

## blah blah blah
## see, class and if are on the same indentation now!

if __name__ == '__main__':
    i1 = Node()
    i2 = Node()
    h1 = Node()
    h2 = Node()
    o1 = Node()

    h1.addParent(i1, 1)
    h1.addParent(i2, 1)
    h2.addParent(i2, 1)
    h2.addParent(i2, 1)
    o1.addParent(h1, -1)
    o1.addParent(h2, 1)

    i1.nodeWeight = 3
    i2.nodeWeight = 5
    calculateWeight(h1)
    calculateWeight(h2)
    calculateWeight(o1)
```

Answer (score 0):

python use indentation for code block

as you put if **name** == '**main**' int the class define code block, it is treated as class declaration, and will be executed, for example:

```py
$ cat /tmp/test_class_statement.py
class demo(object):
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        print 'test'
        x = demo()
```

here i define a class and the interpreter will try to get the definition of class demo, then it found a declaration which actually declare nothing, but it will execute it because python interpreter is dynamically execute interpreted byte stream one instruction and next one, so currently, it doesn't know what you want to declare, then you just print a string, actually fool the interpreter, but it will do execute it.

then a real attribute is declared, it is the 'x', but the class demo has not finished its definition, which means python interpreter cannot look up the result of a class named 'demo', so you get an error: NameError: name 'demo' is not defined

here is the result of execution:

```
$ python /tmp/test_class_statement.py
test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/test_class_statement.py", line 1, in <module>
    class demo(object):
  File "/tmp/test_class_statement.py", line 4, in demo
    x = demo()
NameError: name 'demo' is not defined
```

here is the another one, which proves it can work if the expected class can be found:

```
$ cat /tmp/test_class_statement.py
class demo(object):
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        x = 1

print demo().x
```

here is the output

```
$ python /tmp/test_class_statement.py
1
```

if you import the test_class_statement from another module, which means the **name** is not **main**, then the x is not defined for class demo

so, as the other answers say: you should intent the if **name** == '**main**' code block as the most left align, since is the common way we define the main entry

and the way to call an object's method is: h1.calculateWeight(), not calculateWeight(h1). the h1 is an object reference, which is exactly the 'self', you can treat it as the java's term 'this' if you're familiar with java, this is the rule, i cannot explain it too deep

Answer (score -1):

Fix your indentation. Python is `indent sensitive language`

bring out the definition of `main` from `class` body. The code should look like this:

```
class Node:
    // definition body

if __name__ == '__main__':
    // main body
```